# selectbox with ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 selectboxs

1.areaID

2.cityID

When user choose area in the first selectbox, the second one will be auto change and shows only the cities accourding the selected area.

that works good, except when I load data from the DB or when user submit the form. in those cases the right city doesn't selected - the pointer is always on the first option (first city).

what do I need to change?

```
<p><label>AREA</label> 
    <select name='areaID' id='areaID'>
        <?PHP
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `areas` ORDER BY id ASC "); 
        while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $db_area_id = $index['id'];
            $db_area_name = $index['name'];
            if ($db_area_id == $userDetails['areaID'])
                echo "<option value='$db_area_id' selected>$db_area_name</option>";         
            else    
                echo "<option value='$db_area_id'>$db_area_name</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select><span>*</span>
</p>

<p><label>CITY</label>
    <select id='cityID' name='cityID'>  </select>
</p>


<script>

<?PHP if ($_POST) { ?>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#areaID').filter(function(){
            var areaID=$('#areaID').val();
            var cityID=<?PHP echo $userDetails['cityID'] ?>;
            $('#cityID').load('ajax/getCities.php?areaID=' + areaID+'&cityID=' + cityID);
            return false;
        });
    }); 
<?PHP }else { ?>

$(function () {
    function updateCitySelectBox() {
        var areaID = $('#areaID').val();
        $('#cityID').load('ajax/getCities.php?areaID=' + areaID);

        return false;
    }

    updateCitySelectBox();
    $('#areaID').change(updateCitySelectBox);
});
<?PHP } ?>

</script>
```

getCities.php :

```
<?PHP

    $areaID = (int) $_GET['areaID'];


    $second_option = "";

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE area_id = $areaID ORDER BY id ASC");
    while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query2)) 
    {
        $id = $index['id'];
        $name  = $index['name'];

        $name = iconv('windows-1255', 'UTF-8', $name);

        $second_option .= "<option value='$id'>$name</option>";

    }

    echo $second_option;

//  exit; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<p><label>CITY</label>
    <select id='cityID' name='cityID'>  </select>
</p>
```

To this:

```
<p><label>CITY</label>
    <select id='cityID' name='cityID'>
    <?php
    if (isset($userDetails['areaID']))
    {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities` WHERE area_id = {$userDetails['areaID']} ORDER BY id ASC "); 
        while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $db_city_id = $index['id'];
            $db_city_name = $index['name'];
            if (isset($userDetails['cityID']) && $db_city_id == $userDetails['cityID'])
                echo "<option value='$db_city_id' selected>$db_city_name</option>";         
            else    
                echo "<option value='$db_city_id'>$db_city_name</option>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<option value="0">Select Area...</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: come on...thats not the right way to fix it...
and - what will happened to the script if the user will change the area? does the city selectbox will change? I guess not...

Comment: Yes! This is the right way!! According your code, when user change the Area selection, the method updateCitySelectBox is called.